# blazor validationMessage of dynamic component provided expression contains a InstanceMethodCallExpression1 which is not supported

Tags: c#, validation, blazor

im building some dynamic form generator in blazor and i have issue with this part

```
 @using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.CompilerServices
 @using System.Text.Json
 @using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
 @typeparam Type


<EditForm Model="@DataContext" OnValidSubmit="OnValidSubmit">
<DataAnnotationsValidator/>
 @foreach (var prop in  typeof(Type).GetProperties())
{
    <div class="mb-3">
     <label for= "@this.idform.ToString()_@prop.Name">@Label(@prop.Name) : </label> 
     
        @CreateStringComponent(@prop.Name)

        @if (ShowValidationUnderField)
        {
                   <ValidationMessage For = "@(()=> @prop.GetValue(DataContext))"></ValidationMessage>

        }
      </div>
      
    
}

@code {
[Parameter] public Type? DataContext { get; set; } 

[Parameter] 
public EventCallback<Type> OnValidSubmitCallback { get; set; }

[Parameter]
public bool ShowValidationSummary { get; set; } = false;

[Parameter]
public bool ShowValidationUnderField { get; set; } = true;
}
```

so i get this error

'provided expression contains a InstanceMethodCallExpression1 which is not supported.'

its because of

```
@(()=> @prop.GetValue(DataContext))
```

is there any other way that i can do that 'properly' ? or via builder?
thanks and regards !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ok i finaly found something similar somwhere and modified a bit and it works
so for future searchers:

```
@if (ShowValidationUnderField)
{
     @FieldValidationTemplate(@prop.Name)
}
```

and in code:

```
 public RenderFragment? FieldValidationTemplate(string fld) => builder =>
   {

       PropertyInfo? propInfoValue = typeof(ContextType).GetProperty(fld);

       var access = Expression.Property(Expression.Constant(DataContext, typeof(ContextType)), propInfoValue!);
       var lambda = Expression.Lambda(typeof(Func<>).MakeGenericType(propInfoValue!.PropertyType), access);

       builder.OpenComponent(0, typeof(ValidationMessage<>).MakeGenericType(propInfoValue!.PropertyType));
       builder.AddAttribute(1, "For", lambda);
       builder.CloseComponent();


   };
```

regards

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a typo:

`@(()=> @prop.GetValue(DataContext))` should be `@(()=> prop.GetValue(DataContext))`
(the second @ symbol is not good here)

Can you try it please?

Comment: hi no this toes not change anything. you can have addidtional @ in blazor you just canot have this first one ;P

Answer (score 0):

`ValidationMessage` expects an expression that it can decompose to get the property name.   It uses the `Model` it gets from the cascaded `EditContext` and the property from the `For` to query the `ValidationMessageStore` on the `EditContext` for any messages logged against the Model/Property.

You get the error because the `For` isn't in the correct format.

That's the problem with building Dynamic forms: you also need to build the infrastructure that goes with them.

This is the relevant code in the Blazor repository - https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/66104a801c5692bb2da63915ad877d641c45cd42/src/Components/Forms/src/FieldIdentifier.cs#L91  (good luck!)